# How to return ID from HTML tags containing ID while using beautifulsoup to parse it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to write IDs from html sources to CSV file, but it's difficult for me to find a proper code.

There are two cases that I want to be resolved.

Case1)

```
<footnotes>
    <footnote id="F1">Includes 4,675.96 restricted stock units that will vest and settle in shares of the Company's common stock on a one-for-one basis on February 23, 2012.</footnote>
</footnotes>
```

I want to write this as the following in the CSV file.

Case1 Want)

```
    F1 Includes 4,675.96 restricted stock units that will vest and settle in shares of the Company's common stock on a one-for-one basis on February 23, 2012.
```

Basically, I want to keep "F1", which is its ID, from the tags and to write it with texts in the file.

Case2)

```
<exerciseDate>
    <footnoteId id="F5"/>
</exerciseDate>
```

I want to write this as the following in the CSV file.

Case2 Want)

```
F5
```

I have trouble in finding an appropriate code to write this to the file.

Unfortunately, I have no prepared code.

It would be extremely helpful if you can provide me a way to solve either one of the problems.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: you should ask only one question on the page.

Comment: `soup.find('footnote').get('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Shortly

```
soup.find('footnote').get('id')
```

---

Example code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''<footnotes>
    <footnote id="F1">Includes 4,675.96 restricted stock units that will vest and settle in shares of the Company's common stock on a one-for-one basis on February 23, 2012.</footnote>
</footnotes>
<exerciseDate>
    <footnoteId id="F5"/>
</exerciseDate>'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

item = soup.find('footnote')
print(item.get('id'), item.get_text())

item = soup.find('footnoteid')
print(item.get('id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example code to get you started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """
            <footnotes>
                <footnote id="F1">Includes 4,675.96 restricted stock units that will vest and settle in shares of the Company's common stock on a one-for-one basis on February 23, 2012.</footnote>
            </footnotes>
            """

# ~~ Parse HTML ~~ #
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'html.parser')

# ~~ Find footnote tags in the html ~~ #
footnote_tag = soup.find("footnote")

# From footnote tag, get id
footnote_id = footnote_tag['id']

# From footnote tag, get text
footnote_text = footnote_tag.get_text()

# Putting id with text
return_statement = "ID {0} {1}".format(footnote_id,footnote_text)
```